# Button on ListBox Item

Tags: wpf, listbox, richtextbox

I have a ListBox filled with items. Some of the items may have buttons or links within RichTextBlock inside. I want to fire different action either when the item is pressed or when the button is pressed. The problem is when I hit the button, also the action connected with the item itself is fired. How can I prevent fireing the event of list item when the button inside is pressed?

ListBox:

```
<ListBox x:Name="StripesList" SelectionChanged="StripesList_SelectionChanged">
</ListBox>
```

ListBox Items:

```
<Border x:Name="OuterBorder" Width="400">
    <Image x:Name="ThumbnailBox" Width="100" Source="{Binding Thumbnail}" Tap="ThumbnailClick" />
</Border>
```

Code:

```
private void StripesList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (StripesList != null)
    {
        StripesList.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
}

private void ThumbnailClick(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    Image image = sender as Image;
    // handle image click
}

private void ItemClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // handle item click
}
```

I register item click event observers from code behind:

```
item.Tap += new EventHandler(ItemClick);
```

Comment: Can you include the XAML of your ListBox and the code for your events in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set e.Handled=true in the handler of all events . It will stop the Bubbleing of the event.

Comment: OK, it works for Image. But I also want to have same effect for hyperlinks within RichTextBox, and RoutedEventArgs that it fires does not have Handled property (for WP7)

Comment: I dont Know that , In that case in the beginning of your handler check the source like in ListBox handler check if e.Source is Button then just return or if it is ListBox then proceed.

Comment: Great ! It works, I can determine the source as you said using .OriginalSource property. Thanks!